# Is normal that CPU used is 0% while Mathematica is running for a lot of minutes?

Tags: discussion

I´m a little confused. While Mathematica is running while a lot of minutes, I can see in the administrator (Windows8) that CPU is used in a 0%.

Is that normal?

[image]

Comment: Also look under Processes, where the Kernels are listed.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have: the kernel is running (using approx 30% of CPU) and mathematica has 0% of CPU

[image]